# Fermionic Version of the effective Action

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, grassmann-numbers, 1pi-effective-action

For a scalar field theory one introduces the partition function with external sources

$$
Z[j] = \int \mathscr{D} \varphi \, \exp \left( -S[\varphi] + \int j \, \varphi \right) \text{,}
$$

the analogon of the free energy

$$
F[j] = \ln Z[j] \text{,}
$$

and for the mapping

\begin{alignat}{2}
C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^D) & \longrightarrow \, & C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^D) \\
j(\bullet) & \longmapsto &  \frac{\delta}{\delta \, j(\bullet)} F[j] = \langle \varphi (\bullet) \rangle =: \phi[j] (\bullet)
\end{alignat}

we denote with $j[\phi]$ the formal inverse mapping and define the effective action as

$$
\Gamma[\phi] = - F[j[\phi]] + \int \phi \, j[\phi] \text{.}
$$

I seek to calculate the effective action $\Gamma^{4}$ (within first order perturbation theory) for a fermionic field theory with an action that is quartic in the (Grassmann-)fields.

Peskin, Schwartz, Altland and Coleman (my "standard-literature") don't seem to help.

Comment: could you specifiy better what your problem is? the standard definitions apply for grassman fields too

Comment: So for Grassmann fields one also has $\Gamma [\varphi, \bar{\varphi}] = -F[ j[\varphi, \bar{\varphi}], j^*[\varphi, \bar{\varphi}] ] + \int j[\varphi, \bar{\varphi}] \varphi^* + j^*[\varphi, \bar{\varphi}]  \varphi $ ???

Comment: My problem is that I seek to do a one-loop-approximation and arrive at the fermionic version of the formula $\Gamma_{\text{one loop}} [\varphi, \varphi^*] = S [\varphi, \varphi^*] + \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr} \, \operatorname{log} S^{(2)} [\varphi, \varphi^*]$. But this formula is derived under the assumption that the pair $(\varphi, \varphi^*)$ *extremizes* the action. Now as one is working with Grassmann variables I am unsure of how to interprete something like "extremizing the action".

Comment: Use grassmann derivatives to "extremise" the action. Taylor series work the same way etc @Antihero

Comment: Try Chapters 7 and 8 of  "Dynamical Symmetry Breaking in Quantum Field Theories" by V. A. Miransky

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @alexarvanitakis Is there some sort of relation between the first derivative of S w.r.t. $\varphi$ and the source field $j[\varphi, \bar{\varphi}]$? I can't reproduce the one loop effective action formula from above in the fermionic case. :-( MadMax I've looked into your book but it seems that it only treats scalar field theories and not for Grassmann variables?

Answer (score 1):

The standard definition of the 1PI [effective action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_action) applies to Grassmann-odd fields as well (up to sign-conventions), cf. above comment by user tbt. E.g. Ref. 1 defines in QED

$$ \Gamma[A_{\rm cl},\bar{\psi}_{\rm cl},\psi_{\rm cl}]~=~W_c[J,\eta,\bar{\eta}]-\int\! d^4x (J^{\mu} A_{\mu} +\bar{\psi}_{\rm cl}\eta+ \bar{\eta}\psi_{\rm cl}).\tag{8.1.76}$$

References:

1. L.S. Brown, *QFT,* 1992; eq. (8.1.76).

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the consensus is that it is usual to define the Grassmann analogon of the effective action in a similar way as one does for scalar field theories. For example: It's done in the book from @Qmechanic or [here](https://www.lptmc.jussieu.fr/files/chap_fi.pdf) in chapter 1.6.2.